# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'boto3' has no attribute 'resource' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: pycharm, boto3, boto

Im using Pycharm and installed boto3 package and tried to import boto3 and got attribute error. Python.exe file path is given in project interpreter

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'boto3' has no attribute 'resource' (most likely due to a circular import)

But the same code working in Python shell

Comment: What's your script file name?

Comment: boto3 is filename and im using Python 3.8.2 version and boto3 Version: 1.13.6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess its because of your file name when i tried, i got the same error when renamed the file name. I was able to run the file successfully

Comment: thank you so much abhinaya. yes its because of file name, I should not give the file name as boto3 and not to import the same

Comment: That's funny, I did the same thing.

Comment: For me, I was using the filename `email.py`

Comment: This comment from @varogen helped me. I also had an email.py module in my project, renaming it made it all work fine again. 